# How to get Id from Object in Odoo 10?

Tags: object, odoo, self, odoo-10

This is my structure:

```
class Imprint_Location(models.Model):
    _name = 'imprint.location'

    name = fields.Char()
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template')

class Imprint_Charges(models.Model):
    _name = 'imprint.charge'
    _rec_name = 'location_id'

    product_id_c = fields.Many2one('product.template', required=True)
    location_id = fields.Many2one('imprint.location', required=True)
    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('product_id_c', 'location_id')
    def product_filter(self):
        res = {}
        print '\n\n-------\n\n', self, self.product_id_c, '\n\n-------\n\n'
        if self.product_id_c:
            res['domain'] = {'location_id': [('product_id', '=', self.product_id_c.id)]}
            print res
        return res

class Product_Template(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    imprint_location_ids = fields.One2many('imprint.location', 'product_id')
    sale_imprint_charge_ids = fields.One2many('imprint.charge', 'product_id_c')
```

Now i have defined a page in `product.template` and inside the page is `sale_imprint_charge_ids` which is in `<tree editable="bottom">` and i am not selecting the `product_id_c` field[also this field doesn't show up in the tree defined].

Now my problem here is that when i select this from the form view which i defined for `imprint.charge` the method `product_filter` works fine, but when i enter from the `product.template` then i get a error saying

`TypeError: <odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fbb8bc21b90> is not JSON serializable`

Because from `product.template` if passes the object `<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fbb8bc21b90>` , so if print `self.product_id_c` then it prints `product.template(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fbb8bc21b90>)` so this is not serializable. i have tried doing `self.product_id_c.ids` which give output empty list `[]`.

So how do get the `product.template` id from the object or pass the `id` itself overriding some method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should improve couple of following points.

- res['domain'] = {'location_id': [('product_id', '=', self.product_id_c.id)]}
- return *res*
- study some *search()* method of ORM

Try with following code:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('product_id_c', 'location_id')
def product_filter(self):
    res = {}
    if self.product_id_c:

        self.location_id = False

        #search product_template in imprint.locationwith table and limit we will get only record if related record found
        location_id = self.env['imprint.location'].search([('product_id', '=', self.product_id_c.id)], limit=1)

        if location_id:

            #location_id.ids will give you something like [2] so we need to set value as 2
            self.location_id =  location_id.ids[0]
```

**EDIT:**

As per your first comment, you need a list of related location then we should following trick.

- Remove *product_filter()* method
- Add domain in *imprint.charge* object view file

For example:

```
<field name="location_id" domain="[('product_id', '=', product_id_c)]"/>
```

Afterwards, Restart Odoo server and upgrade your custom module.

Comment: I need to filter the field `location_id`... I only want to show the fields which are of that product...The result could be a list and I want the user to select which `location_id` to select

Comment: Still from the `product.template` i get a empty recordset it passes the `object` not the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a brand new record Odoo creates that wierd `<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7fbb8bc21b90>` object. After you have written the record this id gets turned into the normal ids that you are used to (an integer). In this situation you have a function which (not unreasonably) expects a real id value at a point when no such value really exists. You need to provide a fallback, such as evaluating if the id is an integer and providing an alternate value in that circumstance. Although your function seems to return an object which I dont quite know what you are expecting to happen. If you wish to modify the value of one of your fields I would modify the values of the self object rather that returning an object.